# How to Download 5 files at a time  using Thread in .net framework 3.5

Tags: c#, multithreading, download

I need to download certain files using  FTP.Already it is implemented without using the thread. It takes too much time to download all the files.
So i need to use some thread for speed up the process .

my code is like

```
  foreach (string str1 in files)
   {
      download_FTP(str1)
   }
```

I refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005649/threads-inside-a-foreach-loop-in-c) , But i don't want every files to be queued at ones.say for example `5` files at a time.

Comment: Upgrade your internet line will be the best bet

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @Dee Jay: I cant tell all users to upgrade their internet connection

Comment: @Shebin: The point is, if you have a 1000-Kbit/sec connection, and you run 5 downloads across it at the same time, you'll get 5 streams of 200 Kbit/sec (in a perfect world; it will be less in Real Life of course) instead of 1 stream of 1000 Kbit/sec. In other words, the processing power of your computer is not the bottleneck and downloading multiple files at once from the same server will not give you any significant advantage (it may make it *slower*, though, due to the connection overheads).

Comment: People who downvote, please argue.

Comment: @Piskvor: It depends - if the bottleneck is actually latency rather than bandwidth, or if the issue is with the *peers'* network (e.g. if this code is running on a machine with a good network connection, connecting to multiple machines with poor ones) then using multiple threads *will* help. Shebin, could you clarify that? How large are the files, and to what extent are you already saturating your local network connection?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: The size of each file is 20-40kb.The total number of files be more than 1000. So is their any limitations on the number of threads that i can place?

Comment: @Shebin: Well, you should measure it in various different cases. Are these files being downloaded from different servers, or the same one? Do you have control over the server? (For example, could you put all the files in one big zip archive?)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: All the files are from a single server.The files are downloaded according to the need.say for example sometimes user need only 60 files.No need to download all the files at every time.

Comment: @Shebin: If they're from a single server, then you may find there are restrictions on the number of concurrent connections. If it's a server you control, you might want to consider adding the ability to specify *all* the files in one request, then build a zip file on the fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, as you're not using .NET 4 that makes it slightly harder - the Task Parallel Library would make it really easy to create five threads reading from a producer/consumer queue. However, it still won't be too hard.

- Create a `Queue<string>` with all the files you want to download
- Create 5 threads, each of which has a reference to the queue
- Make each thread loop, taking an item off the queue and downloading it, or finishing if the queue is empty

Note that as `Queue<T>` isn't thread-safe, you'll need to lock to make sure that only one thread tries to fetch an item from the queue at a time:

```
string fileToDownload = null;
lock(padlock)
{
    if (queue.Count == 0)
    {
        return; // Done
    }
    fileToDownload = queue.Dequeue();
}
```

As noted elsewhere, threading *may* not speed things up at all - it depends where the bottleneck is. If the bottleneck is the user's network connection, you won't be able to get more data down the same size of pipe just by using multi-threading. On the other hand, if you have a lot of small files to download from different hosts, then it may be *latency* rather than *bandwidth* which is the problem, in which case threading *will* help.

Comment: @leppie: The thread-pool is typically for *short-running* tasks - it sounds like these could take quite a while to complete. Both would work, of course, but I think it's reasonable to create 5 threads for a producer/consumer approach. Note that you'd still need the producer/consumer model when using the thread pool, as you wouldn't want to just create a work item for each file and set them all going at once.

Answer (score 6):

If the process is too slow, it means most likely that the network/Internet connection is the bottleneck. In that case, downloading the files in parallel won't significantly increase the performance.

It might be another story though if you are downloading from different servers. We may then imagine that some of the servers are slower than others. In that case, parallel downloads would increase the overall performance since the program would download files from other servers while being busy with slow downloads.

EDIT: OK, we have more info from you: Single server, *many* small files.

Downloading multiple files involves some overhead. You can decrease this overhead by somehow grouping the files (tar, zip, whatever) on server-side. Of course, this may not be possible. If your app would talk to a web server, I'd advise to create a zip file on the fly server-side according to the list of files transmitted in the request. But you are on an FTP server so I'll assume you have nearly no flexibility server-side.

Downloading several files in parallel may probably increase the throughput in your case. Be very careful though about restrictions set by the server such as the max amount of simultaneous connections. Also, keep in mind that if you have many simultaneous users, you'll end up with a big amount of connections on the server: users x threads. Which may prove counter-productive according to the scalability of the server.

A commonly accepted rule of good behaviour consists in limiting to max 2 simultaneoud connections per user. YMMV.

Comment: Also, the FTP server might disallow simultaneous connections.

Answer (score 2):

look up on ParameterizedThreadStart

```
List<System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart> ThreadsToUse = new List<System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart>();
int count = 0;
foreach (string str1 in files)    
{
  ThreadsToUse.add(System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart aThread = new   System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(download_FTP));
  ThreadsToUse[count].Invoke(str1);
  count ++;
}
```

I remember something about Thread.Join that can make all threads respond to one start statement, due to it being a delegate.

There is also something else you might want to look up on which i'm still trying to fully grasp which is AsyncThreads, with these you will know when the file has been downloaded. With a normal thread you gonna have to find another way to flag it's finished.

This may or may not help your speed, in one way of your line speed is low then it wont help you much,
on the other hand some servers set each connection to be capped to a certain speed in which you this in theory will set up multiple connections to the server therefore having a slight increase in speed. how much increase tho I cannot answer.

Hope this helps in some way

Answer (score 0):

I can add some experience to the comments already posted.  In an app some years ago I had to generate a treeview of files on an FTP server.  Listing files does not normally require actual downloading, but some of the files were zipped folders and I had to download these and unzip them, (sometimes recursively), to display the files/folders inside.  For a multithreaded solution, this reqired a 'FolderClass' for each folder that could keep state and so handle both unzipped and zipped folders.  To start the operation off, one of these was set up with the root folder and submitted to a P-C queue and a pool of threads.  As the folder was LISTed and iterated, more FolderClass instances were submitted to the queue for each subfolder.  When a FolderClass instance reached the end of its LIST, it PostMessaged itself, (it was not C#, for which you would need BeginInvoke or the like), to the UI thread where its info was added to the listview.

This activity was characterised by a lot of latency-sensitive TCP connect/disconnect with occasional download/unzip.

A pool of, IIRC, 4-6 threads, (as already suggested by other posters), provided the best performance on the single-core system i had at the time and, in this particular case, was much faster than a single-threaded solution.  I can't remember the figures exactly, but no stopwatch was needed to detect the performance boost - something like 3-4 times faster.  On a modern box with multiiple cores where LISTs and unzips could occur concurrently, I would expect even more improvement.

There were some problems - the visual ListView component could not keep up with the incoming messages, (because of the multiple threads, data arrived for aparrently 'random' positions on the treeview and so required continual tree navigation for display), and so the UI tended to freeze during the operation. Another problem was detecting when the operation had actually finished.  These snags are probably not relevant to your download-many-small-files app.

Conclusion - I expect that downloading a lot of small files is going to be faster if multithreaded with multiple connections, if only from mitigating the connect/disconnect latency which can be larger than the actual data download time.  In the extreme case of a satellite connection with high speed but very high latency, a large thread pool would provide a massive speedup.

Note the valid caveats from the other posters - if the server, (or its admin), disallows or gets annoyed at the multiple connections, you may get no boost, limited bandwidth or a nasty email from the admin!

Rgds,
Martin